# Is there a conformal model of hyperbolic plane where the geodesics are straight lines?

Tags: geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, geodesic

Is there a conformal model of hyperbolic plane where the geodesics are straight lines (in the Euclidean sense)?  For example, in the Beltrami-Klein model, geodesics are straight lines, but the model is not conformal.

Note: I am of course *not* asking for the hyperbolic geodesics to have the same *parameterization* as Euclidean geodesics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take your favorite hyperbolic triangle. The sum of its angles will be less than $\pi$.

Now, draw that hyperbolic triangle in some model of the hyperbolic plane where all geodesics are straight lines. The result will look exactly like a Euclidean triangle, and the sum of the angles of this Euclidean triangle will be $\pi$.

So the triangle's angles are not all preserved in the model, meaning that the model is not conformal.